# Duplication of documents inside collection of my Firestore project

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

**I had linked my app to the firestore. Every time the app launches, all the contacts get duplicated inside the collection even if there are same values of the contact. However, in the list view, the contacts got overridden. I want to sync all the contacts from another app that is being connected to the same firestore database itself if by mistake in my app the contact gets deleted.**

```
 if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        ContactModel cm = new ContactModel();
                        cm.id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID));
                        cm.names = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME));
                        int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
                        if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {

                            Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{cm.id}, null);


                            while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                                phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
                                cm.mobileNumber = phoneNumber;


                            }
                            phoneCursor.close();
                            Map<String, Object> contactList = new HashMap<>();
                            contactList.put("contact_id", cm.id);
                            contactList.put("contact_name", cm.names);
                            contactList.put("contact_mobileNumber", cm.mobileNumber);
                            db.collection("Contacts").add(contactList);


                        }
                        contacts.add(cm);


                    }

                    cursor.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
            return contacts;

    }
```

Comment: How does your Firestore atabase look like after running this code?

Comment: At the time of first launch there will be some number of documents containing the various contacts and then at the time of second launch the number of documents will get doubled. So each contact will be present multiple times that's my main concern. I want only one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just now solved the problem. Just put the call of the particular method in which you had loaded all the contacts into the database in `onRequestPermissionsResult()` instead of `onCreate().`

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                           int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                loadContactList();
                loadListView();
                loadContactsIntoDb();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Until you grant the permission, we canot display the list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```